# Something "experience" or "experiences" something

Tags: modifiers

Who can explain why the word **experience** needs the '**s**' on its end?

> "An operation that relies on redundant servers implies the operation **experiences** the minimum amount of downtime during a transition between servers."

Comment: *experience* is a verb here, and follows the normal rules for the **-s** verbal ending. Are you asking for the general rule for whether or not a verb should end with an ***s***?

Comment: General rule please. The operation pertains to net combination of two servers.

Comment: It's still a singular noun, as you're using it: "The operation **pertains** to ..." Similarly, "The operation **experiences** ..."

Answer (score 1):

> "An operation that relies on redundant servers implies the operation experiences the minimum amount of downtime during a transition between servers."

The subject of *experiences* is the second word *operation* - which is singular.  So you use the singular form of the verb.  Subject and verb must agree in form.

*Servers* is not the subject of *experiences.*  This is how the clauses are related.

```
   +--------------------------------------------+
   |                                            |
   |  An operation <--- subject of sentence     |
   |    |                                       |
   |    +-----that relies on redundant servers  <--- modifies "operation"           
   |                                            |    like an adjective
   +-+------------------------------------------+
     |    
  [which] implies <--- verb of sentence
     |
     +---[that] the operation experiences ... <--- the target of "implies"
```

Written with commas it may make more sense.

> "An operation, that relies on redundant servers, [which] implies [that] the operation experiences the minimum amount of downtime during a transition between servers."